# How do I prove the mutual independence of a set of random variables given another set of mutually independent random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variable, independence

Suppose $X_{1},\,\ldots,\, X_{n}$ and $T_{1},\,\ldots,\, T_{r}$
and two sets of random variables, with each $X_{i}$ being categorical,
and each $T_{j}$ being continuous taking on all values in the range $\left[0,\,\infty\right)$. It is known a priori that the T 's are a set of observations that give rise to the distributions of the X 's. How would I prove $\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\bot}}X_{i}\mid\overset{r}{\underset{j=1}{\bot}}T_{j}$?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "observations $(T_1, \ldots, T_r)$ give rise to distribution of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$? If by this you mean 
$$(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = f (T_1, \ldots, T_r)$$
for some function $f$, then your stated independence does not hold, in general. For example, if $T_1,T_2 \sim U(0,1)$ are independent random variables with uniform distribution on the interval (0,1) and

$$X_1 = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  1, & T_1 > 1 / 2\\
  0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.
\qquad
X_2 = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  1, & T_1+T2 > 1 / 2\\
  0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.$$
then $P\{X_1=1\}=1/2$ and $P\{X_2=0\}=1/8$ but $P\{X_1=1,X_2=0\}=0$.